# String replace data retrieved by curl

Tags: php, curl, preg-replace, str-replace

I have created a curl function that returns all the html on a page (along with cookies)

I want to strip out the  information (will also be needing to remove scripts a links brought in)

Here is the code i have

```
<?php
                        /* gets the data from a URL */
                        function get_data($url) {
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            $timeout = 5;
                            $cookie_data =
                              implode(
                                "; ",
                                array_map(
                                  function($k, $v) {
                                    return "$k=$v";
                                  },
                                  array_keys($_COOKIE),
                                  array_values($_COOKIE)
                                )
                              );
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_data);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
                            $data = curl_exec($ch);
                            curl_close($ch);
                             preg_replace('/<meta (.*) \/>/i','', $data);
                            return $data;
                        }
                        echo get_data('http://go.etracc.net/l/25492/2013-12-04/374rh');
                    }
                    ?>
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tags with second parameter specifying which all tags you wish to keep.

http://www.php.net/strip_tags

Example from the doc: to keep a and p tags

```
// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

Comment: But that still keeps the content, I want to remove the following;
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="" name="description">